# Jenkins does not set pruneTags option to true

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

The [Git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) for Jenkins allows [pruning stale tags](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-prune-stale-tags).

When I add (and save) such an option through the Jenkins dashboard:

[image]

The configuration change is the following:
[image]

When the build runs, this option is ignored. Why the option is set to false instead of true?

Jenkins version: 2.222.4

Jenkins Git plugin version: 4.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems a bug to be reported to the [`git-plugin` Jira](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/5edc26da3bd4962bdb8599ef1cbc40d335cd1129/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/PruneStaleTag.java#L63-L74).

The pipeline form (which is tested by the plugin) would be:

```yaml
node {  
  checkout([ $class: 'GitSCM',
             branches: [[name: '*/master']],
             doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
             extensions: [pruneTags(true)],
             submoduleCfg: [],
             userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'remoteURL']]
           ])"
}
```

But if you are not using pipelines and relying on the classic GUI, [`pruneTags (boolean pruneTags)`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/5edc26da3bd4962bdb8599ef1cbc40d335cd1129/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/PruneStaleTag.java#L63-L74) is never called.
Since the code has not changed for the past 2 years, it could be a side-effect of your version of Jenkins 2.x.

Still, I would first upgrade the plugin to the latest 4.10.1, for testing.

---

However, The [OP Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8484783/marc) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518264/jenkins-does-not-set-prunetags-option-to-true/70518436#comment124757004_70518436) to their [issue JENKINS-67473](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67473): "Git plugin does not add pruneTags from UI".
That was closed as too hard to reproduce reliably (with Jenkins 2.319.1 and git plugin 4.10.1.).

> Steps I took to try to duplicate the problem:
>
> 1. Create a freestyle project using git SCM and include the "prune stale tags" setting
> 2. Run the job and confirm that the "Pruning obsolete local tags that do not exist on remotes" message is included in the log
> 3. Create a different freestyle project using git SCM with the JGit implementation instead of command line git and include the "prune stale tags" setting
> 4. Run the job and confirm that the "Pruning obsolete local tags that do not exist on remotes" message is included in the log
> 5. Confirm that the XML definitions of the jobs include `pruneStaleTags` set to `true`
>
> Since there have been multiple security advisories published for Jenkins core since 2.222.4 and multiple security advisories for the git plugin, I recommend upgrading to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: It is a bug but apparently [too hard to replicate](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67473).

Comment: @Marc Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment and relevant extracts from your issue in the answer for more visibility.